# Create a Heatmap that uses modules of genes rather than individual genes in Seurat

Tags: r, seurat, gene-expression, heatmap

Is it possible to create a Heatmap in Seurat that takes in and displays modules of genes as its features rather than individual genes?  So if I have a module of genes associated with a trait or phenotype I can compare the expression of that module across clusters against the expression of other modules of genes.

Currently the way that I am trying to do it is similar to the code below (In this example I am only using one module to test if it works):

```
Module_28 <- readLines(con = "Path_to_file/module28.txt")
Module_28 <- list(Module_28)
Combined <- AddModuleScore(Combined, features = Module_28, ctrl = 5, name = 'Module_28')
names(x = Combined[[]])
avg <- AverageExpression(Combined, features = NULL, add.ident = NULL, return.seurat = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
DoHeatmap(avg, features = c("Module_281"), group.by = "ident", size = 3, angle = 0, draw.lines = FALSE) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7, angle = 45), axis.line = element_line(color = "#ffffff")) + scale_fill_gradient2(low = '#1000ff', mid = "#ffffff", hight = '#aa0101', space = "Lab", na.value = "#ffffff", midpoint = 0, guide = "colourbar", aesthetics = "fill") + coord_flip(expand = TRUE, clip = "on")
```

Often When I try to run the DoHeatmap function I get the following error:

```
Error in DoHeatmap(avg, features = c("Module_281"), group.by = "ident",  : 
  No requested features found in the scale.data slot for the RNA assay.
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: I get an error that I'll add to my post above so you can see it.

Comment: Did you scale your data at some point?

Comment: @haci yes I did scale the data, with the ScaleData() function.